# compilation option FFLAGS in MAKEFILE

Tags: makefile, gfortran, intel-fortran

what does the compilation options mean?
`export FFLAGS = -O3 -r8 -i4 -I${PWD}/headers -nofor_main`.
-r8 means what?i4 means what?where could I find the help file.can anybody explain compilation option FFLAGS?I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently already know that `FFLAGS` is a list of options for a FORTRAN compiler.

`-r8` sets the size of certain data types to 8 bytes, depending on architecture. It is *approximately* the same as setting double precision.

`-i4` sets the default integer size to 4 bytes.

Do you need more?

**EDIT:**

There are a lot of different compilers, and versions of compilers. The default for GNUMake is `f77`, and from the [UNIX man page](http://www-hep2.fzu.cz/computing/htmldoc/f77_sun.html):

> ```
> -r8
>  Double the size of default REAL, DOUBLE, INTEGER, and COMPLEX data.
>
>  NOTE: This option is now considered obsolete and may be
>  removed in future releases. Use the more flexible -xtypemap
>  option instead.
>
>  This option sets the default size for REAL, INTEGER, and
>  LOGICAL to 8, and for COMPLEX to 16.  For INTEGER and LOGI-
>  CAL the compiler allocates 8 bytes, but does 4-byte arith-
>  metic.  For actual 8-byte arithmetic,
>  see -dbl.
> ```

Comment: what is certain type?how to set the size of cetain type to 4 byte?

Comment: Furthermore,where can I get the information about compilation option like i4 and r8

Comment: actually,after I modify r8 to r4,the default real type in Fortran is still 8 byte.I do not know why

Comment: You can't assume that because there is an option `-r8`, there must be an option `-r4`.